# Python not responding in loop

Tags: python, shell

Here is my code:

```
from random import randint
doorNum = randint(1, 3)
doorInp = input("Please Enter A Door Number Between 1 and 3: ")
x = 1
while (x == 1) :
    if(doorNum == doorInp) :
        print("You opened the wrong door and died.")
        exit()
```

now, that works fine, if I happen to get the unlucky number.

```
else :
    print("You entered a room.")
    doorNum = randint(1, 3)
```

This is the part where it stops responding entirely. I am running it in a bash interactive shell (Terminal, on osx). It just ends up blank.

I am new to programming in Python, I spent most of my time as a web developer.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @rawing, I can not yet upvote (newbie), so will put it here.

Comment: Why the `while(x ==1)` loop?

Comment: Is this python2 or python3?

Comment: @Rawing python3 I think.

Comment: @Arun Ghosh it makes it infinite.

Comment: You have an infinite loop.

Comment: @Rishav will that crash it?

Comment: @Ember can you please explain what is that you intend to achieve, as the logic itself of your program is incorrect

Comment: @abhinsit to exit if the user enters a certain number. It is a game.

Comment: Can downvoter please explain why?

Comment: @Ember If I had to guess I'd say the downvotes are because this is such an elementary mistake. We get tons of these every single day, so people have a bit of a short fuse sometimes. Don't worry about them too much. People always downvote for mysterious reasons. You should only be worried if your score is below -2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In python3, the `input` function returns a *string*. You're comparing this *string* value to a random *int* value. This will always evaluate to `False`. Since you only ask for user input **once**, before the loop, the user never gets a chance to choose a new number and the loop keeps comparing a random number to a string forever.

---

I'm not sure what exactly your code is supposed to do, but you probably wanted to do something like this:

```
from random import randint

while True:
    doorNum = randint(1, 3)
    doorInp = int(input("Please Enter A Door Number Between 1 and 3: "))

    if(doorNum == doorInp) :
        print("You opened the wrong door and died.")
        break

    print("You entered a room.")
```

See also: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3, then `input` returns a string and comparing a string to an int is always false, thus your `exit()` function can never run.

Answer (score 0):

Your doorInp variable is a string type, which is causing the issue because you are comparing it to an integer in the if statement. You can easily check by adding something like `print(type(doorInp))` after your input line.
To fix it, just enclose the input statement inside int() like:`doorInp = int(input("...."))`